# Issue with MySQL query taking a long time

Tags: sql, database, mysql

I have the following query running against a mysql database:

```
select value from fact_data 
join entities on fact_data.entity_id=entities.id
where entities.ticker='{value}'
limit 1
```

fact_data is a big table with > 23 million records. If {value} exists in entities.ticker, then the query returns in under a second. But if {value} doesn't exist, the query takes over 2 minutes to return. It is as if a table scan is being done on fact_table. Why wouldn't mysql first do a check to see if there exists an entities.ticker of {value} and then if there isn't, there is no need to do any additional processing.

BTW, here is the output of an EXPLAIN on the above query:

```
id,select_type,table,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,Extra
1,SIMPLE,fact_data,ALL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,23414811,
1,SIMPLE,entities,eq_ref,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,4,findata.fact_data.entity_id,1,"Using where"
```

Comment: Have you indexed entities.ticker?

Comment: Is there an index on entities.ticker? Or on fact_data.entity_id or entities.id?

Comment: The query would take less time when it returns the data simply because it found a match early on and exits since you specify a limit of 1. When there is no value, it keeps going through all the records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an index to the entities.ticker field.
Indexes drammatically speed up query execution time if they are part of the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a common query then you should add an index to your entities.ticker column of the appropriate type, for integers this is trivial, for char you should specify an appropriate length and add a full text index.

As to why mysql doesn't check if there is a value there or not before comparing, it still has to fetch each row and then read that column's value if that column is not part of the primary key or index.